# Additional feature for Post build task Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to check the error log and, in particular, the number of consecutive failures and then integrate the post build task in the Jenkins job?

I want to integrate the **Pagerduty** plugin after my job failure under some specific conditions.

Comment: Hi Piyush, could you possibly provide some more detail about what you are trying to do.  Not sure I quite follow.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am basically running a job in the jenkins and want to integrate the pagerduty as my post build task in case of any job failure. This option is provided in the Jenkins but i want to integrate based on some conditions , like checking failure log or failure code and based on that integrate.

Comment: What information is lacking from the PagerDuty plugin page (https://plugins.jenkins.io/pagerduty)?

Comment: (plugins.jenkins.io/pagerduty) page shows that, in case of failure or unstable build, pagerduty will triggger but i don't want pagerduty to trigger in every failure condition. Like i want for error codes 404 it should trigger but for some other error code it shouldn't. This is required because i dont wan't to integrate pagerduty in case of failure for every codes. I want for specific high alert error codes only.

Comment: you can use groovy postbuild, and write a simple groovy function to grep the logtext for things you need.
can you provide a detailed example of what you want to achieve?